# Implementation of Javascript logic in power fx - canvas app

Tags: javascript, powerquery, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I am pretty new to Canvas app and I was actually looking for implementation of JS logic in power fx. Power fx is a low code language but its very complex while applying the logic to it when the filters are nested. Is there any way I could implement the following JS code in Power fx.

```
let Vehicles = [
  {name:'foo bar', vehicleFeatures: ["Bow", "Feature2"]},
  {name:'hello world', vehicleFeatures: ["Bow", "Row"]},
  {name:'mind games', vehicleFeatures: ["Test"]},
  {name:'new world', vehicleFeatures: ["Bow", "Row", "Feature3"]},

];

let selectedFeaturesToFilter = ["Bow", "Row"];


let filteredVehicles = Vehicles.filter(vehicle=>{
    if(vehicle.vehicleFeatures.every(feature=>selectedFeaturesToFilter.includes(feature))){
        return vehicle;
    }
});

console.log(filteredVehicles);
```

In case of canvas app I have selectedFeaturesToFilter equivalent to the Combobox.SelectedItems and 'Vehicle' and 'Vehicle Features' are two tables with many to many relationship. I need to get the filteredVehicles.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way I could implement the following JS code in Power fx.

Yes, you can do this with PowerFx.
On your `App OnStart`, create the data:

## Vehicles collection

```
ClearCollect(
    Vehicles,
    {
        name: "foo bar",
        vehicleFeatures: ["Bow", "Feature2"]
    },
    {
        name: "hello world",
        vehicleFeatures: ["Bow", "Row"]
    },
    {
        name: "mind games",
        vehicleFeatures: ["Test"]
    },
    {
        name: "new world",
        vehicleFeatures: ["Bow", "Row", "Feature3" ]
    }
);
```

## Features filter

```
Set(selectedFeaturesToFilter, ["Bow", "Row"]);
```

## Filter vehicles with the desired features

```
ClearCollect(FilteredVehiclesCollection,
    ForAll(selectedFeaturesToFilter As featureToSelect,
        Filter(Vehicles, featureToSelect in vehicleFeatures)
    )
);
```

## Merge results

Now, as you have two features to filter, the collection `FilteredVehiclesCollection` has two rows. If you want to have a single row with the filtered vehicles, you need to merge the rows. This code is tricky, but it's working:

```
ClearCollect(FilteredVehiclesCollectionMerged, First(FilteredVehiclesCollection));

Collect(FilteredVehiclesCollectionMerged, ForAll(FilteredVehiclesCollection, Patch(FilteredVehiclesCollectionMerged, ThisRecord)));

Set(FilteredVehicles, First(FilteredVehiclesCollectionMerged).Value);
```

## Screenshots

[image: App OnStart]
[image: Vehicles table]
[image: Features to select]
[image: Results]
[image: Merged result]

Comment: Great answer! in some cases the merging part can be achieved more efficiently with Ungroup().

Comment: Thanks! You're right, `ungroup` and `distinct` could be useful to merge the rows, something like that `Set(FilteredVehicles2, Distinct(Ungroup(FilteredVehiclesCollection, "Value"), name));`

Comment: @jleture Thanks for the response. Actually "Vehicle" and "Vehicle Features" are two tables and has a N:N relationship in dataverse. On the provided formula Filter(Vehicles, featureToSelect in vehicleFeatures), I have replaceed vehicleFeatures with 'Vehicle Features' but received an error "A specified column is not accessible in this context". For more clarification I want to filter the Vehicle based on the Multi Choice Column of Vehicle Features. Is there any way I can filter Vehicles in N:N relationship with multi choice 'Vehicle Features'

Comment: It's probably something like `'Vehicle Features'.value` depending the structure of your table. You should ask the question with more details.